# mysql query returning true when it shouldn't

Tags: php, mysql

This is not dieing as I expected it to, if `$key` is not a value in the `key_code` column of the database. Instead it just continues. I'm probably missing something really simple.

```
$key = $_GET['k'];

$keycheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ib_dist WHERE key_code = '$key'");

if (!$keycheck) {

   die("A database error has occured.");

} else {
```

Comment: This is not how `mysql_query()` actually works. See the manual: http://php.net/mysql_query

Comment: Craziest code. What do you wanna know? This returns if the query was a failure or success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try checking the amount of rows found.

```
$key = $_GET['k'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ib_dist WHERE key_code = '$key'");

if (!$result) {

   die("A database error has occured.");

} else if (0 == mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    // unknown key action
} else {
    // known key action
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_query` returns a resource or `false` based on whether **the query executed successfully**. It does not in any way denote how many rows were returned or whether the query did anything, only whether it executed successfully.

Check how many results where returned or evaluate the returned result separately.

Comment: No, `mysql_query()` returns false if the query fails and a resource if the query executed successfully. It never returns boolean true.

Comment: @Arjan It can return `true`: For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.